# Why is this working in Java but not in C#? a.k.a. how does the scope work in C#?

Tags: c#, java, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Question on C# Variable Scope vs. Other Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2976628/question-on-c-variable-scope-vs-other-languages)

Taken from [here](http://www.javacamp.org/javavscsharp/scope.html) but it's the same problem I had at work today. I'm not a C# programmer, I'm learning.

Java:

```
class Test
{
    double x;
    void F(boolean b) {
        x = 1.0;
        if (b) {
            int x = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

C#:

```
class Test
{
    double x;
    void F(bool b) {
        x = 1.0;
        if (b) {
            int x = 1;//error
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The short version is that within a block one variable name may only refer to a single thing.

Eric Lippert has written blog entries on this subject [Simpe names are not so simple](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx) and [Scope vs Declaration Space vs Lifetime](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/03/what-s-the-difference-part-two-scope-vs-declaration-space-vs-lifetime.aspx)