# My calculator won't work c# console application

Tags: c#, scope, calculator

Its probably a very easy solution but when it gives 3 error messages:

```
The name 'iNum1' does not exist in the current context  
The name 'iNum2' does not exist in the current context  
The name 'soOper' does not exist in the current context
```

When I remove my last line of code it works but without it I can't calculate it. I hope someone can help. Here is the code.

```
//information
    Console.WriteLine("This is a calculator");

    //Let them fill in the first number
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the first number");
    bool bNoNum1 = true;
    while (bNoNum1)
    {

        string sNum1 = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            int iNum1 = int.Parse(sNum1);
            bNoNum1 = false;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That's not a number");
        }

    }



    //Let them fill in (*, +, / of -)
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter +, +, - or :");

    bool bNoOperator = true;


    do
    {
        string sOper = Console.ReadLine();

        if (sOper == "x")
        {
            string soOper = "*";
            bNoOperator = false;
        }
        else if (sOper == ":")
        {
            string soOper = "/";
            bNoOperator = false;
        }
        else if (sOper == "+")
        {
            string soOper = "+";
            bNoOperator = false;
        }
        else if (sOper == "-")
        {
            string soOper = "-";
            bNoOperator = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("De operator " + sOper + " Is niet bekend. Kies uit +, -, x of :");
        }
    } while (bNoOperator);


    //Enter second number
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the second number");

    bool bNoNum2 = true;
    while (bNoNum2)
    {
        string sNum2 = Console.ReadLine();

        try
        {
            int iNum2 = int.Parse(sNum2);
            bNoNum2 = false;
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That's not a number");
        }
    }

    //calculating

    int uitkomst = iNum1 + soOper + iNum2;
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693138/variable-scope-in-statement-blocks

Comment: You're not the first one to run into that problem: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=does+not+exist+in+the+current+context+%5Bc%23%5D

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Math calculator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859111/c-sharp-math-calculator)

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare those 3 variables as a global one's outside your context, put those variables above the line "  like this,

```
Console.WriteLine("This is a calculator");
"
int iNum1;
int iNum2;
string sOper = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare iNum1 and iNum2 at the wrong place - inside some inner brackets. They are not known at the scope where the last line lives. Declare those variables at a different level.

In any case when you will do that you will have another issue: soOper is a string. You are adding an int with a string and with another int.